# How to perform write operation on SpotLED using flutter reative ble?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-plugin

[image: SpoetLED Mask]

I was not able to display content on SpotLED. The one I found is [flutter reactive ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble). I have connected the LED device but could not perform the write operation, it just doesn't display anything.

Here is the sample code

```
  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // print("HEY write pressed");
                      // var fff1=Uuid([00001812,0000,1000,8000,00805]);
                      try {
                        final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
                            serviceId: discoveredServices.last.serviceId,
                            characteristicId:
                                discoveredServices.last.characteristicIds.first,
                            deviceId: widget.viewModel.deviceId);
                        await FlutterReactiveBle()
                            .writeCharacteristicWithoutResponse(characteristic,
                                value: [0xFFFFFFFF]);
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e.toString());
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Send Text')),
```

Remaining code is the example of flutter reactive ble plugin.

I used many bluetooth plugins for connecting and performing the write operation on SpotLED. I just want to display the strings on the LED device through my flutter app.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on the services the device offers? BLE is not that simple, without knowing what the device expects there is no way to write successfully. Without documentation, you might require some sniffing of the traffic and some reverse engineering

Comment: You could start by installing a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to see the services your device offers. Maybe you get some insights there. Feel free to [edit] your question to add your findings